# How to know what Drupal theme is this site using?

Tags: theming, charts

Does anyone know which Drupal theme this site is using? I am interested in purchasing a copy.

http://www.evolution-xy.fr

And also how to create a pedigree chart like that one with Drupal?

http://www.evolution-xy.fr/index/bovin/fiche/66/FR3529132100

When I checked the source code of the site, I found this line. `<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (drupal.org)"; />`, which makes me believe it's a Drupal site.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Identifying a theme on an external site isn't something we cover here, the site could change its theme tomorrow and the answers wouldn't make sense any more.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a custom theme to me. Here is why I think so: I see nothing in the code to points to a known Drupal theme. The theme in the code is called Evolution (name of the site) which usually means a custom theme was built. Also, a search for Evolution Drupal Theme shows nothing that looks like the sites theme. Although, I could be wrong, just a guess.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: I see nothing in the code to points to a known Drupal theme. The theme in the code is called Evolution (name of the site) which usually means a custom theme was built. Also, a search for Evolution Drupal Theme shows nothing that looks like the sites theme. Although, I could be wrong, just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from source of any page. Have a look for the javascript array at the top/bottom of the page that begins with:

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {...
```

There's a setting in that array called "theme" which contains the name of the theme being used for that page.

FYI - The site of yours uses Evolution theme.

Hope that this helps.